# Dangers of echoing arrays in ERB templates

Tags: python, ruby, erb

I have a python script within an erbish template that looks something like this:

```
items = <%= some_array.sort.reverse %>
```

Is this sort of thing dangerous?  What is the proper way to echo a ruby array into a python array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default rendering when calling `<%= ... %>` is through the `.to_s` of the object being rendered. By definition, `.to_s` is not guaranteed to be two-way, and there are ruby constructs which once rendered, can't easily be deserialized (a Hash, for example).

If you know exactly what is going to be in the array you want to render (a list of strings, for example), this might be ok. But if it is not a trivial object, you might want to consider either rendering each item manually, or using a JSON serializer to render the object, rather than relying on `.to_s`:

```
items = json.loads('<%= JSON[some_array.sort.reverse] %>')
```